# Flag module - link's position change (Drupal)

Tags: module, drupal-7, flags

I've just installed Flags module and it looks awful when on the bottom I see "Flag this item" link. The only thing I've found in configuration is enabling it to show as normal link. Still I haven't found how to change position of this link. Is it even possible to change link's place? I have installed CCK Blocks but it doesn't give me any option to get rid of it. If someone know or suspect what's possible - please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Display Suite module, this module is integrated with many modules like flag, title etc...

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your
>   nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having
>   to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list
>   of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

https://drupal.org/project/ds

You can move and generate custom layouts for the fields/properties on the entity display formatter: teaser, full...